# Are Solana Staking rewards paid out automically by the chain?

Tags: solana-program

Are the staking rewards paid out automatically by the chain or is it a manual transaction that is submitted on a regular cadence?

Answer (score 1):

Automatically by the chain. It happens every epoch I believe